# Is there a function like in_array that will check for empty values in PHP?

Tags: php

It is known that `in_array()` function can be used to check if an array contains a certain value. However, when an array contains the value `0`, an empty or `null` values pass the test, too.

For example

```
<?php
    $testing = null;
    $another_testing = 0;
    if ( in_array($testing, [0,1,5,6,7]) )
        echo "Found";
    else
        echo "Not Found";
    echo "<br>";
    if ( in_array($another_testing, [0,1,5,6,7]) )
        echo "Found";
    else
        echo "Not Found";
?>
```

In both cases `"Found"` is printed. But I would like the first case to print `"Not Found"`, and the second case - `"Found"`.

I know I can solve the problem by adding an extra `if` statement, or by writing my own function, but I want to know if there are any built-ins in PHP that can perform the checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is explained by the fact that `null == 0`. But `null !== 0`. In other words, you should check for the types as well.

You don't need another function. Simply pass `true` as the third parameter:

```
in_array($testing, [0,1,5,6,7], true)
```

In this case `in_array()` will also check the types.